# Escribir en un fichero js desde PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

tengo un fichero js el cual inicializa un carrousel de imágenes

Este es el contenido del fichero JS (carrousel.js)

```
var Style = (function(){
    var initCarousel = function(){

        if ($('.js--carousel').length) {
            $('.js--carousel').slick({
                arrows: false,
                infinite: false,
                dots: true,
                autoplay: true,
                autoplaySpeed: 5000,
                speed: 800

            });
        }
  };

    var onReady = function(){
        initCarousel();
        }; 
})($);

Style.init();
```

Desde un fichero PHP cargo este script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="carrousel.js"></script>
```

Lo que necesito es poder añadir los parámetros de autoplay y autoplaySpeed desde PHP.

He probado a añadir esto

```
            $('.js--carousel').slick({
                arrows: false,
                infinite: false,
                dots: true,
                <?php echo "autoplay: ".$activo.","; ?>
                <?php echo "autoplaySpeed: ".$speed.","; ?>
                speed: 800
                
            });
```

Pero no funciona

¿Alguna idea de como poder hacerlo?

Saludos

Comment: Tienes que ser un poco más especifico cuando intentes decir "No funciona", trata de abrir la consola de chrome para ver si te muestra algún error..

Comment: debes pasar el valor de tu expresión php a variables de javascript. Algo como `let php = <?= "autoplay: true"; ?>` y luego sí manejarlo en tu javascript

Comment: Y no se si entendí bien lo que estas intentando hacer... pero si te refieres a que estas cargando tu .js con codigo php escrito en el (dentro del js), no va a funcionar, prueba crear una función que le pases esos dos parámetros

Comment: también asegúrate que sea  `$activo = "true"` y no `$activo = true`

Answer (score 0):

Veo que tienes una instrucción php en un archivo js. Eso no te funcionará porque el servidor no interpreta php dentro de un archivo js. Tienes dos caminos:

1. No uses el archivo externo js, coloca el código en la propia página (un archivo .php). Ahí si se interpretará el código php. Es la más simple y recomendable.
2. Esta es un poco truculenta, en el src del script pones carousel.php () y dentro de este archivo construyes el script javascript con php. Te pongo una muestra: crea este archivo como prueba.php

   ```
    < ?
    $aviso= "mensaje desde php";
    echo <<< EOS
    alert('$aviso');
    //aquí va todo el código javascript
    EOS;
    ?>
   ```

(Ecribe bien las etiquetas de php al inicio y final, el editor no me deja colocarlo aquí)

Si en tu página (puede ser php o html)  pones < script src="prueba.php">< /script> verás que al abrirla se ejecuta el **alert** con el mensaje contenido en la variable php $aviso
Para la página que llama así al php recibe un script en javascript.
¿Te srive?

Comment: Muchas gracias, al final con esto es con lo que me ha funcionado, con algún retoque. En vez de añadirlo como un script. lo he tenido que añadir con un include

Answer (score 0):

Es verdad que no puedes escribir ninguna línea de php dentro de archivos JS. Podrías reestructurar tu proyecto poniendo este código JS en un archivo php que luciría algo asi

```
... mas contenido php aqui ?> 
 $('.js--carousel').slick({
                arrows: false,
                infinite: false,
                dots: true,
                <?php echo "autoplay: ".$activo.","; ?>
                <?php echo "autoplaySpeed: ".$speed.","; ?>
                speed: 800
                
            });
<?php continua el contenido en php...
```

O bien, si deseas mantener este archivo JS independiente, podrias almacenar estas variables previamente en un objeto window para volverlo disponible cuando quieras, also asi:

en tu pagina php

```
?>
<script>
window.autoplay_active = <?=$active?>; 
window.autopla_speed = <?=$speed?>; 
</scrip>
// Luego cargas tu librería de carrousel 
<script type="text/javascript" src="carrousel.js"></script>
<?php ...
```

y luego lo usas como:

```
$('.js--carousel').slick({
                arrows: false,
                infinite: false,
                dots: true,
                autoplay: window.autoplay_active
                autoplaySpeed: window.autoplay_speed
                speed: 800
              
            });
```

Comment: Hola, gracias pero con esto no funcionaba

Answer (score 0):

Cuando digo que "No funciona" es que no hace nada y no me muestra nada en la consola.

He probado a realizar esto

```
var Style = (function(habilitar, vel){
    var initCarousel = function(){

        if ($('.js--carousel').length) {
            $('.js--carousel').slick({
                arrows: false,
                infinite: false,
                dots: true,
                autoplay: habilitar,
                autoplaySpeed: vel,
                speed: 800

            });
        }
  };

    var onReady = function(){
        initCarousel();
        }; 
})($);

Style.init(true, 5000);
```

Esto funciona.

Ahora me voy al fichero php que incluye el fichero JS

Y a continuación comento la linea **Style.init(true, 5000);** en carrousel.js, y añado esto después de incluir el fichero js en el PHP

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="slick.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="carrousel.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript\">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                 Style.init(true, 5000);
            });
    </script>
```

Esto no funciona, ya que no muestra el carrusel, no se inicia el slick y los errores en consola son del slick.js